# (iOS) Word embedding vector is nil when using text from SwiftUI TextField

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, coreml, createml

I'm building an emoji search bar where you can type and get the relevant emojis to show up - similar to what Apple does on its keyboard. For that, I've precomputed static word embeddings for all the emojis and saved it in a `.mlmodel` file. My task is to compute the word embedding for the search query and look it up in the `mlmodel`.

**Issue:** Whenever I try to call `NLEmbedding.vector(for: String)` method, it returns a `nil` value. This happens only when the parameter is linked to a SwiftUI `@State var`. If it is a String literal, than it works perfectly fine.

Here's a miniumum reproducible example for the same.

```
import SwiftUI
import NaturalLanguage

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var searchText = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Search emojis", text: $searchText)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                .cornerRadius(12)
                .onChange(of: searchText, perform: searchEmojis(forQuery:))
        }
        .padding()
    }

   private func searchEmojis(forQuery text: String) {
        guard let embedding = NLEmbedding.wordEmbedding(for: .english) else { return }
        let queryVector = embedding.vector(for: text) // Works fine for a string literal
        print("Query vector: \(queryVector)") // Returns a nil vector
    }
}
```

**What I'm looking for:** A way to retrieve user input and compute the word embedding dynamically.

Comment: After adding `.lowercased()` to text, the model returned some values for the text ***Sad***.

Comment: @Timmy That really helped. I feel stupid :)